# How do I add new language support to eclipse che

Tags: eclipse-che

I'm quite new to eclipse che, and I'm currently trying to figure out how to add a new language support to che. Can anybody help?

Answer (score 1):

You can check https://www.eclipse.org/che/docs/language-servers.html on how to add support for a new language server.

In Che a language server is used to provide all the language functionalities such as syntax highlighting, autocompletions etc.

If might also want to create a stack with the required toolchain to compile source code written in your new language.

Comment: I'm following the LS-sidecar approach and am stuck with an issue which I have raised here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52605341/how-to-include-a-local-language-server-in-a-dockerfile-and-build-a-docker-image